# How can this formula to swizzle rows be simplified?

Tags: algorithm

The problem is quite simple to understand but solving it was not as easy as it sounded at first.

Let's assume the following, an image that is 8*4, normal order is easy, you return the pixel index:

```
// 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
// 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
// 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
// 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Now *suppose* you want to swizzle rows like so:

```
// 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
// 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
// 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
// 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

I solved it, not without trouble to be honest, with the following formula:

```
index / 8 % 2 * 16 + index / 16 * 8 + index % 8
```

Isn't there a simpler formula to get the same result?

Comment: I think the key question is how do you expect it to extend for more rows or columns. For example, according to this formula, the next row will be `16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23`, but this row has already appeared previously. So how do you define the swizzle for more rows?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that swizzling can become complex depending on the image size and the pattern in which the rows are being swapped. Simplifying the formula beyond this point might lead to a loss of accuracy or incorrect results.

Comment: @JadeHamel "loss of accuracy"? why are you posting this chatgpt BS?

Comment: Why not just apply a swizzle matrix to each column? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swizzling_(computer_graphics)

Comment: @Maurycyt That's an excellent question I haven't thought about!

Comment: @Berthur Just tested it, it really is the way go, amazing!

Comment: @aybe is the matrix the way to go? I wouldn't say so. Multiplying by a matrix is inefficient both timewise and memorywise. But, if it floats your boat, then I guess that's good.

Comment: Yep, you are right, the initial excitation vanished, though it is smart and does work, I just realized that it also has shortcomings as you've just mentioned.

Comment: @Maurycyt well it scales similarly to the formula. If you only need swizzling in batches of 4, then you just need a 4x4 matrix which is of constant size. Moreover, it is massively paralellizable on a GPU (which fits well with the image processing topic here) and a lot more suitable for both customization and readability.

Comment: In the end, both of you are right somehow :)

Comment: Formula with 7 operations: `(index & 16) >> 1 | (index & 8) << 1 | index & 7`

Comment: @Ack amazing simplification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `/` and `%` return the **quotient** and **remainder** in the Euclidean division:

The classic ordering can be obtained as:

```
row = n / 8
col = n % 8
```

And the swizzled ordering can be obtained as:

```
col = n % 8
old_row = n / 8
new_row = 2 * (old_row / 2) + (1 - (old_row % 2))
```

Explanation:

- `2 * (old_row / 2)` groups the rows two by two;
- `(1 - (old_row % 2))` swaps row `0` and row `1` of each group.

Comment: This should be equivalent to swapping (or XORing) bit 3 and bit 4 of the row number. If I'd only knew how to write that in Python ;)

Comment: @Ack This is equivalent to switching the least-significant bit of the row numbers. I'm not sure what bits you mean when you say "bits 3 and 4".

Comment: @AcK Also, if you want to write the code above in python3, all you have to do is replace `/` by `//`.

Comment: That's an interesting alternative but I believe the comment up above is just the most sane way to do that, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant bits 3 and 4 of n.

Comment: @aybe You mean using a matrix? Aaaaaand how would you build that matrix? ... By using `%` ;-)

Comment: Good question, looking into it!

Comment: I accept your answer as it's an interesting alternative I haven't thought of. About matrices, problem is not so much avoid modulo but they are limited on the range you process. Of course it can be addressed but then you end up in more *convolutions* than needed ;)